# Python importError with f2py

Tags: python, windows, fortran, f2py

I'm using `Intel OneAPI` & `f2py` to biuld a python module. I already have the module named `<module name>.cp310-win_amd64.pyd`. When I use `import <module name>` I get the error `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing <module name>`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve]. You must show the *exact steps*. Not some `<module name>`, but the exact module name, the exact commmands and the exact error messages.

Comment: Are you using the correct interpreter for the import? (CPython 3.10 on AMD64.) If you are, use e.g. Dependency Walker or a similar tool to see if the DLL depends on something that's not on your path.

Answer (score 0):

I am having troubles related to this, yet not finally solved, but your problem so far seems to be solved if you copy the content dll from the generated module folder, inside libs, to your local directory. At least the error should be different.

Comment: Hello, your contribution would fit better as a comment than as an answer.

Comment: The problem has been solved by using `--compiler=gnu95`. Maybe something is wrong with Intel OneAPI.

Comment: @LionelHamayon i agree with you, but it happens now that I want to edit this, that either I delete my post or rather it will get forgotten since right now I do not have the 50 points of reputation. Sorry.